# Sitecore:Getting 404 Error after defining physicalFodler path in SiteDefination.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, sitecore

We have a multisite solution & recently added one more site to this.
For this we added a new entry in our SiteDefination.config as follow:

```
<site name="MyNewSite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            hostName="stc.local"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/www/Brand International"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/International"
            startItem="/Brand Name/My Site Node/home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="10MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"/>
```

in one of the layout(.aspx page),we are defining css/js/images paths like below:

```
<script src="/Brand Name/My Site/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
```

Our full physical path under root is as below:

```
www
    Brand International
        Brand Name
             My Site
                 js
                     jquery.placeholder.js
                     .....
                 css
                     global.css
                     ....
```

In browser we are getting 404 error,with following path for file:

```
<script src="/Brans Name/My Site/js/jquery.placeholder.js">
```

Comment: try this `./Brand Name/My Site/js/jquery.placeholder.js`  the layout.aspx is in the Brand International folder?

Comment: no the layout goes in/www/Brand International/Brand Name/My Site/layouts/Main.aspx
Also ./Brand Name/My Site/js/jquery.placeholder.js is not working :-(

Comment: use `<script src="../js/jquery.placeholder.js">` it will look for js in My Site Folder.

EDIT : make sure the script is in Main.aspx only And not the Master Page of that file

Comment: it will work but that way it will expose full path in html source file.

Comment: can u pastebin the source or the path

Comment: Is the 's' a typo in the SO post? (Brans Name). If not, then that might be the issue.

Comment: The location should be relative a relative path to the IIS root folder. If it is `www`  then try just `/Brand International` - http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/physicalFolder.aspx

Comment: @JayS:Its a typo in the So post.

Comment: @jammykam : Path in IIS is defined as C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project_Name\website

Comment: Are you getting a Sitecore 404 or a default IIS 404?  If you are getting default IIS 404, then Sitecore is not even handling the request and that explains the problem, as IIS would know nothing about the physicalFolder setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore PhysicalFolder works only for aspx files.no out of the box solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `runat=server` to the script/css/js links and use `~/`

`<script runat="server" src="~/Brand Name/My Site/js/jquery.placeholder.js">`
Not the Best practice

Comment: A request by the browser for resources has nothing to do with `runat=server` tags